# Is this sentence grammatically correct? "the birth a planet the size of Jupiter"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage, adjective-phrases, postpositive-adjectives

Consider:

> Scientists recently witnessed the birth a planet the size of Jupiter...

You can find the original article [here](http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2015/12/08/4366144.htm).

I have two questions:

1. I think it must be the birth "**of**" a planet, am I wrong?
2. I think the sentence needs a preposition before "**the size of**".

Would you please shed light on grammatical structure of this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is grammatically incorrect:

> ...witnessed the birth a planet...

Since it was **the birth of** *something* that was witnessed, you need to add **of**:

> ...witnessed the birth **of** a planet...

A preposition before **the size of** is not necessary:

> ... a planet the size of Jupiter.

This is an **adjective phrase** that describes the planet that was being born.

> Scientists recently witnessed the birth **of** a planet the size of Jupiter.

Comment: So, it is correct to say" an object the size/length/depth/height/X.... of another object". Can any noun be substituted by the X, i.e., "an object the beauty of another object" ?

Comment: "An object the size **of** X" is well used, but "an object **with** the depth **of** X", or "A girl **with** the beauty **of** the open sky". Maybe because contractions occur with greater usage(?)

Comment: We could fix this sentence another way, by changing the start of it – we could remove the definite article before _birth_: _Scientists recently witnessed a star system birth a planet the size of Jupiter._ This usage of _birth_ as a verb would be grammatical, but the preceding "the" found in the original messes that up.

Comment: @Peter I didn't get your point about "contractions occur with greater usage", would you explain it to me

Comment: If one looks at the usage of phrases, the more a phrase is used the faster it tends to **evolve** (possibly also in meaning).  This evolution usually involves a shortening of the phrase for efficiency. This also happens in many other languages. One can imagine the comparison of size: *something* **with the size of**, to have been used so many times it became shortened to *something* **the size of**. An example in French might be **I don't know**: *Je ne c'est pas* which has become shortened to *c'est pas* (pronounced "shay-pa", mainly in Paris).  With extensive usage, an **idiom** may occur.

Comment: Hope that helps.

Comment: @Peter it does, tnx